# ¿Como recortar el número de decimales impresos después de un cálculo de promedio?

Tags: php, mysqli

Intento que después de hacer el calculo de promedio de calificaciones o notas, imprimiendo el promedio obtenido solo con un número decimal después del punto pero usando la función `round` si le dejó `$rpromedio = round($promedio,1);` lo esta redondeando hacia arriba y si ocupo `$rpromedio = number_format($rpromedio1, 1, ',', '');` también lo esta redondeando hacia arriba.

Pero solo necesito que del promedio obtenido lo imprima con un solo número decimal después del punto.

Ejemplo: Calificaciones: 8, 8, 10, 9, 9, 6, 8, 9,  Promedio = 8.375
Busco que imprima solo: 8.3. Sin redondear

Usando:  `$rpromedio = round($promedio,1);` Pronedio = 8.38

Usando  `$rpromedio = number_format($rpromedio1, 1, ',', '');` Promedio = 8.4

```html
     $promedio = $suma/$contador;  

  //$rpromedio = round($promedio,2);  //función que tenia antes
  $rpromedio = number_format($promedio, 1, ',', ''); //intente recortar a un solo decimal con esta función pero lo esta redondeando hacia arriba.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es ocupar `floor()`, que hace un redondeo hacia abajo:

```
$rpromedio = floor($promedio * 10) /10;
```

Así puedes mantener solo el primer decimal.

Comment: gracias ¿porque multiplicarlo y divirlo el valor dentro de la funcióm?

Comment: Disculpa la demora. Eso es por que `floor()` retorna la parte entera: `floor(1.65) = 1`.

Comment: Gracias saludos

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
function truncateFloat($number, $digitos)
{
    $raiz = 10;
    $multiplicador = pow ($raiz,$digitos);
    $resultado = ((int)($number * $multiplicador)) / $multiplicador;
    return number_format($resultado, $digitos); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `substr` junto con `strpos` para cortar el número (como un string) luego del punto:

```
$rpromedio = substr($promedio, 0, strpos($promedio, '.') + 2);
```